# How to make Startup PIN make a loud noise

Tags: encryption, nexus-6p

My phone unexpected rebooted itself this evening while I was cycling.  This was unfortunate, because I was logging my ride with GPS, and my phone was inside a pack where I could not tell it had rebooted.  Worse still, even though the logging app would have automatically detected that logged was enabled and restarted logging, causing me to only lose a couple minutes of data, the device itself was stuck at the boot screen waiting for a PIN.  The reboot happened about one minute into my ride, and thus my entire ride was **lost**.

I have done some research and have found that the only way to disable encryption on my phone involves unlocking and flashing a new bootloader and reformatting the entire flash, which has risks of its own and I am not comfortable doing at this time.  So barring that I would like some way to know when my phone is wanting me to enter the PIN so it can boot, so that when I am running a logging application I don't lose all my data simply.

How can I make my phone forcibly alert me when it wants this info?  Preferably a loud tone of some kind that would persist until the PIN is entered.

Update: Ok, apparently after a while the device starts making a faint clicking noise, but this is nothing I would ever hear while outside.

Comment: Maybe you should try using headphones while cycling? Because I don't think there is a way to increase the volume.

Comment: @zackygaurav yeah, i may have to resort to having my app send a periodic "pulse" sound through my bluetooth headset so i know it is alive.  still not great for unattended logging, but it at least works around the issue in some cases.  for now i will probably just reboot the phone nightly in the hopes that this will get rid of the spurious reboots.